# Force Wordpress to use https for embeds

Tags: wordpress

I've recently switched my Wordpress v4.3.1 blog to `HTTPS` resulting in YouTube videos to stop working. A blank area is displayed instead of the video player. This is because Firefox blocks `http` content when the page is served through `https`.

Wordpress converts YouTube links in a post to `iframe` HTML code but seems to ignore `https`.

I've tried using shortcode as follows, without success:

```
[youtube=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxZ_ZznO2ek]
```

I've also tried `apply_filter` as described in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/forcing-ssl-return-for-youtube-oembed but without success. This could be related to `apply_filter` not being applied properly.

```
$content = get_the_content();                       
add_filter('the_content', 'add_secure_video_options', 10);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

What other options do I have left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See step 4 of https://www.bram.us/2014/12/06/migrating-your-wordpress-website-from-http-to-https/: you'll need to update the contents of your database to use https embeds.

For example:

`# Update YouTube embeds
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.youtube.com');`

For oembeds this is a different thing, as they are not stored in `wp_posts`. When quickly Googling around oembeds are cached in `wp_postmeta` *(cannot verify, as I don't use oembed)*:

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_oembed%"`

You'll need to replace these using a replace query as seen in the instructions above. Of the top of my head:

`# Update YouTube oembeds
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'http://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.youtube.com');`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
[embed width="123" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in a non-Wordpress way:

```
$content = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.youtube.com', $content);
$content = str_replace('http://youtube.com', 'https://youtube.com', $content);
```